# Multiprocess on my Raspberry pi won't stop

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, video-processing

I have a multiprocess script which runs as expected on my normal computer, but when I run the same script on my raspberry pi 3 A model via thonny, stopping the script doesn't seem to stop the process.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=video_player, args = ([resizer(img,70)]))

    p.start()
```

the video_player() function takes a list of images from the resizer() function and uses cv2 to continuously play them. Running this on my laptop, I can simply use a keyboard unterrupt to cancel the script, but on my raspberry pi, the images keep playing after I stop the script and I don't seem to be able to cancel this window at all and so have to shutdown the rasp pi each time.

Answer (score 0):

usually making the child process a daemon process causes it to exit when the main process exits therefore solving the issue.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=video_player, args=(resizer(img, 70),), daemon=True)

    p.start()
    p.join()  # wait for ctrl-C event
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I found this doesn't fix my issue, although I can elaborate that it seems to be a problem cause by the work environment. When I run the same script from a terminal instead of thonny, the ctr c event appears to stop all processes as expected.